# Safari refreshes the page on setting 'animation-play-state' to paused;

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, safari-web-inspector

Something weird is happening here... I am trying to stop my CSS animation on hover and it's work great on: Chrome | Firefox | IE but not in Safari (all my browsers are latest versions) so Safari refreshes the whole page on hover!! Whaaaat? How???

Thank you for your attention.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JQkcL/#&togetherjs=Kjfsh0wkiT)**

```
<body bgcolor="#FF6666">
    <div id="about-to-continue" class="more-arrow-maindiv home-arrow-position">
        <span class="more-arrow-title hp-more-arrow-title">Scroll Down</span>
        <span class="more-arrow more-arrow-hp blink_eff"></span>
    </div>
</body>
```